# Android - App Specific Logging

Tags: android, battery

I would like to log the following:
1. App Name
2. App Open time
3. App Close time
4. Energy consumed by that app in that session.

I searched a lot and couldn't find a right direction. I know there's no simple solution and Android SDK's public API do not allow this. But I assume that this would be possible on a rooted device.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Catlog app logs details of rooted devices. It is a opensource. You might get some idea here https://github.com/nolanlawson/Catlog.

Comment: Hi, It just shows me each activity that's happening. Can you please tell me how to get each app's consuming battery level?